# Improving the quality of test stubs

Tags: web-services, testing, soap, websphere

I have recently finished working on a project where we were the client testing a vendor's integrated software solution. The vendor did not have access to our test environments and hence used test stubs to test their web service calls. Due to the poor quality of their stubs they got numerous false positives which led to several defects during system integration testing.

Now the roles are reversed. I am now representing a vendor coordinating testing against test stubs for a WebSphere solution. I am concerned about this given my recent experience. Unfortunately testing against a fully integrated environment is not possible as the development is being done off shore.

How can I ensure our test stubs adequately reflect the complexities of an integrated environment?

Comment: Test stubs are useless. Useless with a capital U. :-( Unless you can  create intelligent stubs, which is quite a lot of work, your static stubs will only return what you already know. It will prove your mappings work but will give you no confidence around the data you are returning. When using web services to return data from legacy system using stubs is an absolute no-no.